# How to link ibOutlet from subview to custom UIView Class in storyboard xcode

Tags: xcode, uiview, storyboard, interface-builder, iboutlet

I think this image explains it all. I have a subclass of UIView that I've entered into the class field. I'm trying to connect ibOutlets between the storyboard and class implementation. It's not giving me an error, but it's not working either. Is this another xcode bug, or am I expecting this to work in a way that it won't?

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is a solution:

1) Type an IBOutlet **by hands** in your header file, *example*:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet ProgressBarElementView *targetProgressElement;
```

2) Drag the pin **from the code** to the *element* in document outline zone

[image]

Comment: Make sure the view has been set as the custom class otherwise this won't work.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.. I saw that if you add the custom class to the root view in the view controller, it will work.. In your case this is the initial View, listed under Bottom Layout Guide

But there must be a better way

Answer (score 0):

To overcome XCode stubborness, especially when you need to hook up different enums from `UIControlEvent` than `UIControlEventTouchUpInside`, I'd rather use code directly from within the custom view class:

*SWIFT*

```
button.addTarget(self, action:#selector(ClassName.handleRegister(sender:)),
                          for: .touchDragExit)
```

*OBJECTIVE-C*

```
[self.button addTarget:self
                action: @selector(buttonTouchDragExitAction:)
      forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragExit];
```

One might include such code in `awakeFromNib` or `viewDidLoad` or where it best suits.

Answer (score 0):

write the outlet inside your custom UIView

```
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
```

then drag it into the storyboard on the view